# Upgrade SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to upgrade my SQL Server. I get the following message:

[image]

I currently have SQL Server Developer edition. I went to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads and clicked on the Developer:

[image]

After clicking on the downloaded executable, I did not see an option to upgrade.. Wondering if I may have downloaded the wrong file. I currently have the following installed:

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583456) - 14.0.2037.2 (X64)   Nov  2 2020 19:19:59   Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 10.0  (Build 19042: )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the download at that link choose "Custom Installation" or  "download installation media", and from the full installer you will be able to upgrade SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition to SQL 2019 Developer Edition.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH